# How do I prevent inserting new records into tables while using Linq and SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

When creating a new object that is mapped to one of my SQL Server tables, LINQ inserts a new record into the table when I call SubmitChanges.  I want to prevent this, but still need my new object.

I know about the custom methods, but is there anyway to disable this behaviour so that it just updates existing records and never inserts new records, regardless of if I've called `MyTableClass myObject = new MyTableClass()` or not.

Thanks.

Comment: The "new" by itself won't do anything... you'd need to go out of your way to add it (Attach/InsertOnSubmit) to the context...?

Answer (score 3):

If you want your data-context to barf at inserts, you can do:

```
partial class DataClasses1DataContext
{
    public override void SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode failureMode)
    {
        if(GetChangeSet().Inserts.OfType<MyObject>().Any())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No inserts!");
        }
        base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
    }
}
```

Any good?

[was:
Could you simply add it as "clean" - i.e. Attach(obj, false);

If you don't want the object in the model, why add it to the data context?]

Comment: Because I still need to be able to retrieve the data and update the data, just not insert.

Comment: Thanks.  It's not all inserts i want to prevent though, just one table.  I will give your Attach(obj, false) a go, but will have to pass the datacontext around all my objects, which i don't like.

Comment: Can you clarify: is this a child on a new/existing record?

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a stored procedure which doesn't do anything and allocate that to the insert role - it's a real hack but it'll get the job done!

I would suggest that perhaps the fact that this issue is coming up indicates that there's something wrong with the approach you're taking in referencing this object - what precisely necessitates the use of this new object?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not prevent it at the server side? Connect as a role which doesn't have insert access. Sooner or later, that's going to be the most bulletproof way of preventing inserts, I suspect.

Comment: We use windows auth, so using one app they can insert, but other apps they shouldn't, for example.